# Form won't post

Tags: php, html, post, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm experimenting with PHP/POST/etc to help me at my day job as a Webdev.  From the tutorials, etc, I've seen online, this should work.  However, when I click submit, the page is redirected to `bagelBack.php`, but there's a blank page, and the tweet is not submitted.  I'm on my own machine, using XAMPP Apache.  (There is jQuery on the HTML page, if that helps)

EDIT: It's failing on line 40 of the php (`$connection->request`, etc).  `var_dump`s work, but `echo` does not.  I'm new to all this.  Why is this not throwing an error?

Html:

```
<form id="bagelForm" action="bagelBack.php" method="POST">
    <label for="twitterName">Twitter Name: </label><input type="text" id="twitterName" name="twitterName"/><br />
    <label for="bagelType">Bagel Type: </label><input type="text" id="bagelType" name="bagelType"/><br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

PHP (Mostly from [here](http://140dev.com/twitter-api-programming-tutorials/hello-twitter-oauth-php/)):

```
<?php
/**
* bagelBack.php
* Example of posting a tweet with OAuth
* Latest copy of this code: 
* http://140dev.com/twitter-api-programming-tutorials/hello-twitter-oauth-php/
* @author Adam Green <140dev@gmail.com>
* @license GNU Public License
*/

$name = "@".$_POST['twitterName'];
$type = $_POST['bagelType'];

$tweet_text = $name.", your ".$type." bagel has finished toasting!";
$result = post_tweet($tweet_text);
echo "Response code: " . $result . "\n";

function post_tweet($tweet_text) {

  // Use Matt Harris' OAuth library to make the connection
  // This lives at: https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth
  require_once('tmhOAuth.php');

  // Set the authorization values
  // In keeping with the OAuth tradition of maximum confusion, 
  // the names of some of these values are different from the Twitter Dev interface
  // user_token is called Access Token on the Dev site
  // user_secret is called Access Token Secret on the Dev site
  // The values here have asterisks to hide the true contents 
  // You need to use the actual values from Twitter
  $connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
    'consumer_key' => '[redacted]',
    'consumer_secret' => '[redacted]',
    'user_token' => '[redacted]',
    'user_secret' => '[redacted]'
  )); 

  // Make the API call
  $connection->request('POST', 
    $connection->url('1/statuses/update'), 
    array('status' => $tweet_text));

  return $connection->response['code'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to var_dump($name) the variables to see if there is anything?  Also have you tried to remove the post_tweet function and just see if you can get the posts to go to the next page?  Is the filename correct?

Comment: Have you tried `echo $name;` and `echo $type;`? What do you see?

Comment: The variables are POSTing fine.  The issue is in `post_tweet`  Why would it die like that without displaying an error?

Comment: You may have your errors not displaying or something.  Is your tmhOAuth.php is the same location as the bagelBack.php?

Comment: PHP error_reporting is set to E_ALL & ~E_STRICT.  Yes, it is in the same directory.

Comment: Its possible that this API is not being used anymore and you may not be getting a response.  Best way to check this is to change the return to true or return a string, if it works then there is something wrong with the API your using.  I would check twitter to make sure its the most up to date version.  EDIT***Looks like this one is using Version 1 while there is an updated version

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this article a while ago when experiencing the same issue:

http://www.highonphp.com/php-fastcgi-post-requests-failing

It has to do with fcgi vs cgi SAPI's that the webhost has installed.

Comment: I'm POSTing fine to my PHP.  The issue is the post_tweet function.